# Merge two user data dictionary data into a single dictionary having same user data in python

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, dictionary

Here the Problem is Explained. I ahve Users having multiple skiils . Showing Data like the Problem with seperate skills data
Solution I needed for same user's skills will be at same array data.

## Problem: Data is LIke this Type:

```
{
    'group'= 'GR-A',
    'users'=[   {
                    'id' = 1,
                    'name' = 'A'
                    'skills' = {
                        'id' = 1
                        'name' = 'skill-A'
                    }
                },
                {
                    'id' = 1,
                    'name' = 'A'
                    'skills' = {
                        'id' = 2
                        'name' = 'skill-B'
                    }
                },
                {
                    'id' = 2,
                    'name' = 'B'
                    'skills' = {
                        'id' = 2
                        'name' = 'skill-B'
                    }
                },
            ]
}
```

## Data Solution Needed:

```
{   'group'= 'GR-A',    'users'=[   {
                    'id' = 1,
                    'name' = 'A'
                    'skills' = [
                        {
                            'id' = 1
                            'name' = 'skill-A'
                        },
                        {
                            'id' = 2
                            'name' = 'skill-B'
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    'id' = 2,
                    'name' = 'B'
                    'skills' = [
                        {
                            'id' = 2
                            'name' = 'skill-B'
                        }
                    ]
                },          ] }
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show your code and state specific problem that you have.

Comment: I am getting the problem data from the database query. And I have to arrange the data as the needed solution data

Comment: That is clear. However SO is not code writing service. You need to show your code for solviing this task and explain the problem you cannot solve.

Comment: The data isn't in python format ... You realize this, yes?

Answer (score 1):

Considering dictionary provided is valid grouping on perticluar key can be done using `itertools.groupby` function.

Check the follwoing code

```py
from itertools import groupby
from pprint import pprint

data = {'group': 'GR-A', 'users': [{'id': 1, 'name': 'A', 'skills': {'id': 1, 'name': 'skill-A'}},
                                   {'id': 1, 'name': 'A', 'skills': {'id': 2, 'name': 'skill-B'}},
                                   {'id': 2, 'name': 'B', 'skills': {'id': 2, 'name': 'skill-B'}}]}

users = []
for k, v in groupby(data['users'], key=lambda x: x['id']):
    temp = {}
    for temp_dict in v:
        temp = dict(temp, **{k: v for k, v in temp_dict.items() if k != 'skills'})
        if temp.get('skills') is not None or temp.get('skills') == []:
            temp['skills'].append(temp_dict.get('skills'))
        else:
            temp['skills'] = []
            temp['skills'].append(temp_dict.get('skills'))
    users.append(temp)
data['users'] = users

pprint(data)
```

Gives output:

```
{'group': 'GR-A',
 'users': [{'id': 1,
            'name': 'A',
            'skills': [{'id': 1, 'name': 'skill-A'},
                       {'id': 2, 'name': 'skill-B'}]},
           {'id': 2, 'name': 'B', 'skills': [{'id': 2, 'name': 'skill-B'}]}]}
```